# How to solve the error "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders." in a monorepo project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarn-workspaces

I created a monorepo for my React project.

This is what I did:

- Created a react project
- In its root: created a `workspaces` folder
- In the workspaces folder: created two react apps that will share code
- Added the following to the `package.json` in the root:

  ```
   "workspaces": [
    "workspaces/*"
  ]
  ```
- Changed the names of the different project in their `package.json` files to `@reponame/packagename`
- Added a dependency (e.g., `"@reponame/sharedcode": "*"`) to the `package.json` files
- Added a component that exports a component

  ```
    const TEST = () => {
        return <div>TEST</div>
    };

    export default TEST;
  ```
- Consumed the component in my app

  ```
    import TEST from "@teamcenter-extension-monorepo/shared/src/components/TEST";

    const App = () => {
      return (
        <TEST />
      );
    }

    export default App;
  ```

Now when I run this, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ../shared/src/components/TEST.tsx 4:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:11)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ../../node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| const TEST = () => {
>     return <div>TEST</div>
| };
|
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Notes:

- The two react apps are created identically
- The react apps work as intended without sharing code
- As soon as I start sharing code, things to sideways!